# Get Facebook autocomplete list when posting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

When you create a new post on Facebook, and use the @ (at sign), when typing you get an autocomplete list of friends and pages liked.

Do you have any idea how to get this list using Facebook's Graph API? Or maybe some other solution? I am using Facebook CSharp SDK, so maybe there is a way using this library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not tag users in normal posts or comments made via API.

The only situation where that is possible, is in Open Graph stories.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#tags

---

If you need the user’s liked pages also, then you need to request `user_likes` permission from them beforehand. (But I rather doubt that Facebook will approve the use of the permission for this purpose in review.)